# How to zoom in using Mouse Position on that image

Tags: c#

I have a userControl library, which consists of the main Panel and a PictureBox, I want to make a zoomable PictureBox tool, I zoom in and out using mouseWheel event of the main Panel, the problem that I can't figure out how do I zoom in by the mouse position on the image, so whenever I zoom in, the zoom goes the Top-Left corner of the panel, so how do I fix that?

```
private double ZOOMFACTOR = 1.15;   // = 15% smaller or larger
private int MINMAX = 5;
void picPanel_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            ZoomIn();
        }
        else
        {
            ZoomOut();
        }
    }

    private void ZoomIn()
    {
        if ((picBox.Width < (MINMAX * this.Width)) &&
            (picBox.Height < (MINMAX * this.Height)))
        {
            picBox.Width = Convert.ToInt32(picBox.Width * ZOOMFACTOR);
            picBox.Height = Convert.ToInt32(picBox.Height * ZOOMFACTOR);
        }
    } 
    private void picBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (picBox.Focused) return;
        picBox.Focus();
    }
```

**Update :**

I have tried this, it looks like working, but not exactly as it should be!! Any ideas?

```
    private void ZoomIn()
    {
        if ((picBox.Width < (MINMAX * this.Width)) &&
            (picBox.Height < (MINMAX * this.Height)))
        {
            picBox.Width = Convert.ToInt32(picBox.Width * ZOOMFACTOR);
            picBox.Height = Convert.ToInt32(picBox.Height * ZOOMFACTOR);

            Point p = this.AutoScrollPosition;
            int deltaX = e.X - p.X;
            int deltaY = e.Y - p.Y;
            this.AutoScrollPosition = new Point(deltaX, deltaY);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the example of Zoom image on mouse position....
tested verified.

```
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs ea)
{
    //  flag = 1;
    // Override OnMouseWheel event, for zooming in/out with the scroll wheel
    if (picmap1.Image != null)
    {
        // If the mouse wheel is moved forward (Zoom in)
        if (ea.Delta > 0)
        {
            // Check if the pictureBox dimensions are in range (15 is the minimum and maximum zoom level)
            if ((picmap1.Width < (15 * this.Width)) && (picmap1.Height < (15 * this.Height)))
            {
                // Change the size of the picturebox, multiply it by the ZOOMFACTOR
                picmap1.Width = (int)(picmap1.Width * 1.25);
                picmap1.Height = (int)(picmap1.Height * 1.25);

                // Formula to move the picturebox, to zoom in the point selected by the mouse cursor
                picmap1.Top = (int)(ea.Y - 1.25 * (ea.Y - picmap1.Top));
                picmap1.Left = (int)(ea.X - 1.25 * (ea.X - picmap1.Left));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Check if the pictureBox dimensions are in range (15 is the minimum and maximum zoom level)
            if ((picmap1.Width > (imagemappan.Width)) && (picmap1.Height > (imagemappan.Height)))
            {
                // Change the size of the picturebox, divide it by the ZOOMFACTOR
                picmap1.Width = (int)(picmap1.Width / 1.25);
                picmap1.Height = (int)(picmap1.Height / 1.25);

                // Formula to move the picturebox, to zoom in the point selected by the mouse cursor
                picmap1.Top = (int)(ea.Y - 0.80 * (ea.Y - picmap1.Top));
                picmap1.Left = (int)(ea.X - 0.80 * (ea.X - picmap1.Left));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a lot extra going on in this answer, but This is the math i was looking for     picmap1.Top = (int)(ea.Y - 1.25 * (ea.Y - picmap1.Top));      so thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your control is acting like a viewport - the origin is top left, so every time you stretch the image you're doing it from that corner - the upshot is you wind up zooming into the top left corner, you need to offset the stretched image and centre the point the user zoomed in on.

- image size: 200,200
- user clicks 100,50 and zooms in x2
- stretch the image
- image size 400,400, and the place the user clicked is now effectively at 200,100
- you need to slide the image 100 px left and 50 px up to correct for re-sizing the image

You'll need to override the `paint` event handler to draw the image offset:

```
 RectangleF BmpRect = new RectangleF((float)(Offset.X), (float)(Offset.Y), (float)(ZoomedWidth), (float)(ZoomedHeight));
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(Bmp, ViewPort , BmpRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

*Bmp is your image; ViewPort is a Rectangle defined by your pictureBox control*

Here is [a thread](http://qa.social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/136ba4f8-a487-4e21-b146-300ec4738d2e) that might help.

Comment: I have updated the question, can you help me with the answer?

Comment: im sorry, it's still not clear for me, i would prefer to use it in my way with out override paint event of the picBox, because i need the Scroll in the main panel to be used, please notify me when if you update your answer.